# How to create 3D Box designs with User-Generated Dimensions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, 3d, photoshop-scripting, template-design

I'm trying to learn [how to make 3D Box Images in Photoshop](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-software-box-in-photoshop-using-actions--psd-11009). I need this for box designs of different sizes, and so I found this tutorial that makes it easy to create with the use of Photoshop Actions.

While fast-reading the tutorial, I found around Step 10 onwards, the shape of the box is explained on how to shape it... For me, I need these shapes of different sizes (varied length, depth, and height).

How can I set the shape to be varied on user's input? For example, when the action is running, how can I alter the tutorial's method to ask user input for the length, depth and height?

Also, is there ANY software (free/paid) that can let me create these boxes hassle-free? Any Action/script/template in Photoshop that can let me change the dimensions as per requirement?

Thanks.

[image: 3D Box Image]

Comment: @Scott: Yes, That's a question I asked some time ago... I was looking for suggestions to external tutorial's option for user-generated input.... Or any suggestions for a software/plugin/action?

Comment: Read that question and it's comments.....

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will refer to that question for further help then.